# Jquery Datatables Pagination SInfo not updating

Tags: jquery, api, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables and Loading the data from server side. When I am performing a delete on server side, I am calling the following client function in parallel :

```
function clientDelete(rowId) {
           var dataTable = $('#loadedDepartments').dataTable();
           var nRow = $('#loadedDepartments tbody tr[id=' + rowId + ']')[0];
           dataTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow, null, true);
       }
```

so the process is delete server side-> delete client side

lets assume we have 3 records, the SInfo of the pagination text is **"Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries"**
the first delete works perfect and SInfo of the pagination is updated  **"Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries"**
the second deletes works perfect (row is deleted on both client and server side but) SInfo is not updated it is stuck on    **"Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries"** while it should decrement.

Those are the initial settings of my datatable

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({

            "bDestory": true, 
            "aaSorting": [],
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
            }
        } );
```

Any help please ?

Comment: I dunno, maybe it's a bug? You can try to search or ask also @ datables forum: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adatatables.net%2Fforums+SInfo

Comment: Can you post your pagination code (bootstrap)?  A simple fiddle shows that the functionality works without the pagination code, so I suspect it's the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/QLP65/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Datatables. If you move your info outside of the custom div it will work right away. Like so:

```
"sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<...>ip"
                                                 ^^
```

It's annoying that the bug exists. There are currently too many bugs reported for datatable to have any hope that this one will be fixed any time soon but here's hoping for version 1.10